# How to mark closed question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to make "h1" simulate "p" as if "h1" is "p" in CSS or JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076615/how-to-make-h1-simulate-p-as-if-h1-is-p-in-css-or-js)

I'm aware that question is duplicate as [How do I get a computed style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style)

How to mark my closed question as a duplicate of that question?

Comment: your question is unclear ...

Comment: The question is already closed. No reason to worry about changing the closure reason.

Comment: The only benefit would be auto redirection for unregistered users...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a question is closed there is no option to mark it as a duplicate.

What you could do is leave a comment that links to the duplicate. That will be noticed by visitors of your question. Adding that comment with link also populates the Linked Questions block at the right hand side of the screen.

If you really want to have the question closed as duplicate, you would first have to re-open vote it (needs at least 3 users with close/re-open privileges) and then 5 close voters (3K > rep) or a single dupe hammer (gold tag badge holder) to close it against your proposed duplicate.

That feels like a lot of work for a lot of users while there is little gain.

Don't worry too much about it. I would leave your question as is.

Comment: Do note that in many places, the system considers duplicate closures as "there's nothing wrong with the question except that it's a duplicate". For instance, duplicate closures don't result in migration rejection, and duplicates are ineligible for `RemoveAbandonedClosed` Roomba deletion. For this reason, if the question's a duplicate *and* it's also eligible for another reason, I go with that other reason.